# Using opaque return type `some`: Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

```
protocol Shape {
    associatedtype Something
    func describe() -> String
}

struct Square: Shape {
    Something = String
    func describe() -> String {
        return "I'm a square. My four sides have the same lengths."
    }
}

struct Circle: Shape {
    Something = Int
    func describe() -> String {
        return "I'm a circle. I look like a perfectly round apple pie."
    }
}

func makeShape() -> some Shape {
    if someConditionPasses {
        return Circle()
    }
    return Square()
}
```

The above won't compile and results in the error: `Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types`.

It will only compile if I return one or the other Shape items, either `Circle` or `Square`.

How can I achieve the sort of result that will let me return the type I want? I thought that `some` is for.

Comment: Just do `func makeShape() -> Shape`. `some` is for when you have _one_ type you want to return, but you don't want the caller to know.

Comment: Right, and thanks for your response. I actually missed a crucial point in my question and I've now updated it. It's just that the protocol has an `associatedType` and therefore won't let me return the protocol as the type

Comment: Well then you need a type eraser. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66220761/swift-make-two-types-with-the-same-shape-conform-to-a-common-protocol/66220961#66220961).

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62605936/12299030?